# MIPS code refuses to load. Freezes QTSpin immediately

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to write a program that calculates the factorial of a given integer. For whatever reason I can not even get it to load into Qtspin without the program freezing. I assume somewhere I start an infinite loop without realizing it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#Calculates the factorial of a given integer

main:
        li $t0, 4
        syscall
        move $a0, $t0

        jal fact
        beq $a0, $zero, End

fact:
        addi $sp, $sp, –8 # adjust stack for 2 items
        sw $ra, 4($sp) # save the return address
        sw $a0, 0($sp) # save the argument n

        slti $t0,$a0,1 # test for n < 1
        beq $t0,$zero,L1 # if n >= 1, go to L1

        addi $v0,$zero,1 # return 1
        addi $sp,$sp,8 # pop 2 items off stack
        jr $ra # return to caller

L1:
        addi $a0,$a0,–1 # n >= 1: argument gets (n – 1)
        jal fact # call fact with (n –1)

        lw $a0, 0($sp) # return from jal: restore argument n
        lw $ra, 4($sp) # restore the return address
        addi $sp, $sp, 8 # adjust stack pointer to pop 2 items

        mul $v0,$a0,$v0 # return n * fact (n – 1)

        jr $ra # return to the caller

End:
        li $v0, 10
```

Comment: Have you tried MARS?

Comment: Why do you `bgtz $a0, fact` ? It should be a `jal`. Otherwise the `jr $ra` will jump to garbage.

Comment: Ok I've tried that. Still freezes on load up.

Comment: Why is the jump to `End` conditional?

Comment: Also, what's the point of that `syscall` at the beginning? I don't see `$v0` being initialized to a system call number prior to that. And why is there no `syscall` after that `li $v0, 10` at the end?

Comment: Michael, Thank you for pointing that out. I hadn't thought it through. Still, I can't seem to get the damn thing to load.

Comment: Try MARS instead of QtSpim.